# How to breaking lambda into multiple lines for debugging

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am trying to debug something but this one statement got so much in it so it is very hard to debug it. It has multiple functions and a lambda in it and it won't step into TraceRoute method for me to debug. I am thinking of breaking it into a few lines of codes in order for me to step into the method. What would be correct way to do this!

```
 WService(Of ICService).Use(Sub(svc) traceMessage = svc.TraceRoute(), False)
```

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by clicking inside the lambda and hitting F9.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I'm wondering if you could use '_' to put it on multiple lines.

Comment: Tried cursor in lambda and and hit F9 it still didn't work. How to use '_' to put it on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with it, make it a subroutine/function until you know it's working correctly.